# Unable to connect keyboard to my EKEN tablet

Tags: external-keyboard

I have a 7 inches Android EKEN tablet running ICS. It has Cortex A9 1.5 Ghz CPU.

I also have a leather case with USB keyboard which when connected to my tablet doesn't seem to work - nothing happens.

How can I make the keyboard to work?

Comment: Not enough information to say. Can you collect `logcat` information on what's going on when connecting the keyboard? Maybe that gives some clue.

Comment: you might need to have a powered hub for your keyboard. It might be taking too much power from the tablet for it to function properly.